# Edit fetched KML element by id

Tags: javascript, html, dom, kml, google-earth-plugin

Maybe someone has ideas why function getObjectById(id) does not work in Google earth? I have fetched kml to DOM, but then I try to found element with id it does return nothing.

I am playing in google earth api playground, maybe it does not support extra lybrary?

Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAuPsJpk3MBtDpJ4G8cqBnjRRaGTYH6UMl8mADNa0YKuWNNa8VNxQCzVBXTx2DYyXGsTOxpWhvIG7Djw" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://earth-api-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/tags/extensions-0.2.1/dist/extensions.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

................


// fetch the KML
      var url = 'http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/NetworkLink/placemark.kml';
      google.earth.fetchKml(ge, url, finished);
    }

    function failureCallback(errorCode) {
    }

    function getObjectById(id) {
    var foundObject = null;

    // Traverse the DOM, looking for the object with the given ID.
    gex.dom.walk({
    rootObject: ge,
    visitCallback: function() {
      if ('getId' in this && this.getId() == id) {
        foundObject = this;
        return false;  // Stop the walk.
         }
       }
      });

      return foundObject;
    }

    function buttonClick() {
      getObjectById("p");
      alert("Found:" +foundObject);
    }
```

KML gets loaded, button works, but it seems like getObjectById("p"); does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think there is a `getObjectById()`, you will most likely need to use either `getElementByUrl()` or `getElementById()`

Since you are using fetchKml, I think you should use `getElementByUrl()` like this:

```
var url = 'http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/NetworkLink/placemark.kml';
var object = ge.getElementByUrl(url + '#' + id);
```

[See this page for details](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/accessors)

Comment: I was doing it according to this: [Accessing Google Earth DOM](https://developers.google.com/earth/articles/domtraversal)

Comment: are you loading the gex properly? ie in your init(instance) function do you first load the ge, then the gex as such: ge = instance;gex = new GEarthExtensions(ge);

Comment: why not just use the functions I mentioned in answer - they are supported by the default plugin so no need to load the extensions (unless you use them elsewhere)

Comment: I am working on it, maybe there is a way to display selected item, like "alert(object)"? I can`t found a way to check if it is working on my app, because server is Ubuntu :)

Comment: It did the job :) Maybe you know a quick way to set view on fethed kml ?

Comment: look into .getAbstractView() - or ask as another question on stackoverflow.